# Searching in dynamics documents

Tags: mongodb, search, dynamic, document

I have a dynamic generated document in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51895b7e84c4ac8d9d8cc381"),
    "data" : {
        "404" : {
            "4" : [
                {
                    "linkid" : 4047758,
                    "url" : "http://www.google.com"
                }
            ],
            "5" : [
                {
                    "linkid" : 5031490,
                    "url" : "http://www.yahoo.com"
                },
                {
                    "linkid" : 145929,
                    "url" : "http://www.bing.com"
                },
                {
                    "linkid" : 26710160,
                    "url" : "http://www.msn.com"
                }
            ],
        },
        "405" : {
            "4" : [
                {
                    "linkid" : 4047758,
                    "url" : "http://www.gmail.com"
                }
            ],
            "5" : [
                {
                    "linkid" : 5031490,
                    "url" : "http://mail.yahoo.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I'm basically new in MongoDB world, I have researched how to perform search to know if a url exists in the document, but haven't found something useful so far.

I need for example confirm that a particular URL (http://www.google.com) exists there.

Any help.

Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest that you read a bit more about collection/data modeling in MongoDB, as this schema won't be efficient to index/search.

Comment: Yes, sadly this is something I inherited, and it seems to works fine for it purposes

Comment: What do you mean, it "seems to work fine"? It doesn't work fine for efficient MongoDB querying.

Comment: ideally, the "keys" shouldn't be values in MongoDB. When they are, efficient indexing is nearly impossible when the keys are variable.